# How to Write Native C++ Debugger Visualizers in gdb/ TotalView for Complicated Types

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, totalview

How to Write Native C++ Debugger Visualizers in gdb/ TotalView  for Complicated Types.
i Mean suppose we have one complex type which contains again more different types.
how to get debug symbol of these complex type.
Note: for Reference you can look at link which is for Visual Studio. But i need for gdb/TOtalView on linux.
http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83

thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for the link to the article for MSVS...something I'm looking for a while :-)

Answer (score 7):

GDB and TotalView are completely different products.

Instructions for GDB are [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html).

Instructions for TotalView are [here](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/totalview-family/totalview/docs/8.12/index.html#page/Reference_Guides/CreatingTypeTransformations.html). If that link doesn't work, google has a [copy](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:4swAd985risJ%3awww.totalviewtech.com/support/documentation/totalview/ttf.pdf+totalview+type+transformation+facility&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgIJ6MSlpZmm2pb7EXwdOIkiIC2CBbZ6rErQlguzf9uwN0rrZqWt2tWngvhPKKaicsoEqCPpi2UYtY2Pqq_Xv8TehD9Zu279B8t083iZ6FXqNcLjsV2EtwBamTZhsETaDDoGg6R&sig=AHIEtbR_qXeal_bjM6ACMsn-ZW3Iib9dsQ).

Answer (score -1):

I think the C++ View feature from [TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx) is what you are looking for. To confirm that, you may want to have a look at the following video: [TotalView: Introducing C++ View](http://vimeo.com/50411222).
And more information can be found in the online documentation.